# Django admin reset search box query on filter selection

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following class in Django admin of a model:

```
class TopUpsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('user__email', 'user__phone_number',)
    list_filter = ('status',)
```

Currently the default behavior of the filter is

`if search box in the listing page is input with test_1 which is a user name and search up the result(url will have the following parameter /?q=test_1) , if select an option in the filter then the filter results also got affected by the search box query on the URL ?q=test_1&status__exact=1)`

I would like to not have the search results filter the list when i choose a filter.

Reading Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) only provide me how to override the filter with existed query in the parameter(which come from search box).

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: What if a user wants to do both -- search and filter? I think it should be left the way it is and leave it up to the user to clear out the search input if and when they want.

Comment: @xyres i understand that but currently i need to reset the search result on filter option select as of requirement for my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [**Admin `SimpleListFilter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) and apply the below mixin

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class FilterMixin:
    def choices(self, changelist):
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() is None,
            'query_string': changelist.get_query_string(remove=[self.parameter_name, 'q']),
            'display': _('All'),
        }
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                'selected': self.value() == str(lookup),
                'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup}, remove=['q']),
                'display': title,
            }
```

---

#### Complete code-base

```
#models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    class GenderChoice(models.IntegerChoices):
        MALE = 1
        FEMALE = 2
        OTHER = 3

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GenderChoice.choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# admin.py
class GenderFilter(FilterMixin, admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Gender'
    parameter_name = 'gender'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return Person.GenderChoice.choices

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(**{'gender': int(self.value())})
        else:
            return queryset


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_filter = (GenderFilter,)


admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: very useful i didn't know about FilterMixin so that a big help!

Comment: there is no class named `FilterMixin` in Django, I created it because it can be reused in every **`SimpleListFilter`** class to get the same behavior. @LinhNguyen

Comment: oh it's not a based  class ? then i can just put choice within GenderFilter :)

Comment: Yes, of course. But, I wouldn't prefer that since it will ruin the readability. Moreover, if you want the same behavior in many filters (say you have 3 `list_filter` items), c&p the **`choices()`** code will an ugly process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override `get_search_results` method. See the documentation:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

Example:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        if len(request.GET) > 1:
            search_term = None
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request,
                                                            queryset,
                                                            search_term)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```